# Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIBarButtonItem?' how to set CollectionView into setEditing mode

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

The `setEditing` function is not working and can't call the newFunc function. how can I set `CollectionView` into `setEditing` mode using the default systemItem `.done` and `.edit`

How can I also remove any array item in the cell in `setEditing` Mode?

```
@IBAction func editFunc(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.setEditing(!self.isEditing, animated: true)
      let newFunc = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:      (self.isEditing) ? .edit : .done , target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.editFunc))
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem(newFunc, animated:true)
}
```

Comment: Following up from ["Why downvote for no reason?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795310/why-downvote-for-no-reason), I don't think is a good question. I know nothing about this topic, but one google search of `rightBarButtonItem` took me to the docs for [`UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624957-rightbarbuttonitem), which clearly explains it and shows that it's an instance property, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Please **read** the error message. It says that `rightBarButtonItem` is not a function.

<kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on the symbol to see its declaration. It's a property

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newFunc
```